# Seek not working when multiple HTML5 Audio files are on the same page

Tags: html, django, for-loop, audio, seek

I have multiple HTML5 Audio players loading different sources within a `for-loop` on the same page.
The audio players work perfectly and are playable but when seeking to a specific position, the audio restarts.
I am unable to seek at all. Whether I'm using the HTML5 audio player or an audio library such as [plyr](https://plyr.io/#audio).

After some debugging, I concluded the issue is due to having multiple HTML5 Audio players on the same page. 
Seek works fine with one audio player but anymore on the page, as I'm doing in my `for-loop`, breaks it.
What is the best solution around this?

I'm using Django 2.2 but I'm confident that is not related to the issue.

See my code below -

```html
{% for song in songs %}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4">
  <div class="card shadow-sm">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title mb-4">{{ song.title }}</h4>
      <div class="row mb-2 px-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <audio id="{{ song.id }}" class="js-player" preload="auto" autobuffer controls>
            <source src="{{ song.song.url }}" type="audio/mp3" />
            <source src="{{ song.song.url }}" type="audio/ogg" />
          </audio>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="float-left text-left">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ song.id }}"><i class="fal fa-info-circle ml-3"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="float-right text-right">
        <a href="{{ song.song.url }}" download>Download <i class="fal fa-cloud-download-alt ml-3"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I should be able to load different audio players within my `for-loop` and be able to seek through each one.